# python-docx - lxml.etree.XMLSyntaxError: AttValue length too long

Tags: python, memory, lxml, docx

I am writing a program to check for the presence of a word in a bunch of .docx files (we're talking roughly 2,500 .docx files.

Here's the juicy part of the code:

```
for filename in directorylist:
    if filename.endswith(".docx"):
        i = Document(filename)

        print(filename)


        for destination in destinationlist:
            for paragraph in i.paragraphs:
                if destination in paragraph.text:
                    destinationcount[destination] = 1
                    break
                else:
                    destinationcount[destination] = 0
                    continue

        for destination in destinationcount:
            destinationcountnobool[destination] += destinationcount[destination]

    else:
        continue
```

Now, I know what you're thinking, it's an attrocious mess of loops and shitty programming in general, but this is quick and dirty work so spare me.

Here's the error I am getting:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "ICrunchMeSomeFiles.py", line 27, in <module>
    i = Document(filename)
  File "C:\Users\User\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\docx\api.py", line 25, in Document
    document_part = Package.open(docx).main_document_part
  File "C:\Users\User\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\docx\opc\package.py", line 130, in open
    Unmarshaller.unmarshal(pkg_reader, package, PartFactory)
  File "C:\Users\User\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\docx\opc\package.py", line 199, in unmarshal
    pkg_reader, package, part_factory
  File "C:\Users\User\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\docx\opc\package.py", line 216, in _unmarshal_parts
    partname, content_type, reltype, blob, package
  File "C:\Users\User\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\docx\opc\part.py", line 191, in __new__
    return PartClass.load(partname, content_type, blob, package)
  File "C:\Users\User\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\docx\opc\part.py", line 231, in load
    element = parse_xml(blob)
  File "C:\Users\User\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\docx\oxml\__init__.py", line 28, in parse_xml
    root_element = etree.fromstring(xml, oxml_parser)
  File "src\lxml\etree.pyx", line 3236, in lxml.etree.fromstring
  File "src\lxml\parser.pxi", line 1876, in lxml.etree._parseMemoryDocument
  File "src\lxml\parser.pxi", line 1764, in lxml.etree._parseDoc
  File "src\lxml\parser.pxi", line 1127, in lxml.etree._BaseParser._parseDoc
  File "src\lxml\parser.pxi", line 601, in lxml.etree._ParserContext._handleParseResultDoc
  File "src\lxml\parser.pxi", line 711, in lxml.etree._handleParseResult
  File "src\lxml\parser.pxi", line 640, in lxml.etree._raiseParseError
  File "<string>", line 2
lxml.etree.XMLSyntaxError: AttValue length too long, line 2, column 11011745
```

The program works fine for smaller samples, so I am assuming it's a memory problem. Help would be very much appreciated

EDIT: Should have done this earlier, but have updated the post with the entire snippet of code which causes the error.

```
import csv
from docx import Document
from collections import Counter
import os

directorylist = os.listdir(os.getcwd()) # Set directory here
destinationcount = Counter()
destinationcountnobool = Counter()
destinationlist = ["test1", "test2", "test3", "test4", "test5"]
print(directorylist)

for filename in directorylist:
    if filename.endswith(".docx"):
        i = Document(filename)    


        for destination in destinationlist:
            for paragraph in i.paragraphs:
                if destination in paragraph.text:
                    destinationcount[destination] = 1
                    break
                else:
                    destinationcount[destination] = 0
                    continue

        for destination in destinationcount:
            destinationcountnobool[destination] += destinationcount[destination]

    else:
        continue


for d in destinationcountnobool:
    print(d + " : " + str(destinationcountnobool[d]))
```

**UPDATE: I've been studying this problem for a while now... It seems as if python can only process 118 files before running into this same error.**

**UPDATE: Solved! Kinda... I guess. I've posted my answer**

Comment: Do we have any way of reproducing this?

Comment: @AMC Have updated with the enough code to reproduce the problem - should have done that first, my bad.

Comment: Sorry, just thought about this again, this error only shows up when I process more than 118 files, it seems.

Answer (score 0):

I think can solve your issue :

```
import os
from collections import defaultdict

directorylist = os.listdir('.')


destinationlist = []
destinationcount = defaultdict(int)


def return_each_paragraph_from_file(directory):
    for filename in directory:
        if filename.endswith(".docx"):
            i = Document(filename)
            for paragraph in i.paragraphs:
                yield paragraph


if __name__ == "main":
    for p in return_each_paragraph_from_file(directorylist):
        for destination in destinationlist:
            destinationcount[destination] += 1 if destination in p.text else destinationcount[destination]
```

Comment: Can you explain what the issue was?

Comment: Let me try this

Comment: Just did. I'm afraid this confuses me. When I stuck a 'print' at the end to check whether 'destinationcount' got it right, the values are all zero - so this doesn't seem to be working. I suspect I don't really get this.

Answer (score 0):

Okay, after a fair bit of deduction. I finally figured out what was up. It seems it was a memory issue.

I briefly entertained the hypothesis that the .docx file had some sort of unknowable character which caused the programme to crash. But upon closer examination, I concluded that this was unlikely, seeing as the files were very similar.

Next course of action was to duplicate this project and decrease the sample size to only the amounts that were processed before it failed. The number was 118.

I tried adding and subtracting a file and I always seemed to run into the hard limit of 118. The 119th file always caused it to crash. The fix was quite simple.

```
for filename in directorylist:
    if filename.endswith(".docx"):
        i = Document(filename)    


        for destination in destinationlist:
            for paragraph in i.paragraphs:
                if destination in paragraph.text:
                    destinationcount[destination] = 1
                    break
                else:
                    destinationcount[destination] = 0
                    continue
        del i

        for destination in destinationcount:
            destinationcountnobool[destination] += destinationcount[destination]
```

I just needed to delete the object to free memory. Also, `with` doesn't work with python-docx it seems.

Phew... That's that.

EDIT: Still curious as to why it processed fine until 119th file. Would be glad if someone could enlighten me.

Answer (score 0):

Had the same error (`lxml.etree.XMLSyntaxError: AttValue length too long`) when parsing an SVG.

Using an [`XMLParser`](https://lxml.de/api/lxml.etree.XMLParser-class.html) with `huge_tree=True` resolved the issue.